# Route parameter constraint 'mongoId' not resolved. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have route constraint for MongoDB ID detection.

**MongoIdConstraint.cs:**

```cs
public class MongoIdConstraint:IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey,
                      RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"[0-9a-f]{24}", 
                RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, 
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            
            if (!values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var value)) return false;
            var parameterValueString = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return parameterValueString != null && regex.IsMatch(parameterValueString);
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("mongoId", typeof(MongoIdConstraint));
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("culture", typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint));
    options.AppendTrailingSlash = false;
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
});
```

But it doensn`t work:

[image]

What did  I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to change

`var regex = new Regex(@"[0-9a-f]{24}",...`

to

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9a-f]{24}$",...
```

Your regular expression seems to be incorrect, you can refer to the example：https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference